# A question on the complex grassmann

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, grassmannian

The set of $k$-dimensional complex-linear subspaces of $\mathbb{C^n}$ is denoted by
$G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$. Show that $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ has a unique smooth manifold structure making
it into a homogeneous $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$-space, with the action of $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$
induced from its usual action on $\mathbb{C}^n$. Show that $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is compact, and
determine its dimension.

I already solved this for real numbers could anybody help me solve this for complex numbers?

Comment: What part of the real argument can you not replicate with $U(n)$ in place of $O(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the homogeneous coordinate of $x\in G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ as

$$x=\left[\begin{array}{}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1n}\\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2n}\\
\cdots &        & \cdots &       \\
x_{k1} & x_{k2} & \cdots & x_{kn}
\end{array}\right]
$$
where the matrix is of full rank $k$.

---

Next, we define an equivalence relation. Two element $x,y\in G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ are said to be equivalent if there exists $M\in GL(k, \mathbb{C})$, such that $Mx=y$. The quotient space under this equivalence is clearly $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$, since each element consists of $k$ row vectors that together span a $k$-dimensional subspace, and two set of vectors represent the same subspace if and only if they linearly represent each other.

---

Clearly $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n$), given in this manner, is a $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$-space. Let $x, \in G_k(\mathbb{C}^n), N\in GL(n, \mathbb{C})$, define $N(x)=xN$, where the RHS is matrix multiplication. Since $N$ is nonsingular, $xN$ is of full rank, hence in $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$.

---

To show that $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is compact, let $S=\{m\in M(k\times n, \mathbb{C}): \text{the rows are orthogonal to each other and of length 1}\}$. $S$ is closed and bounded, hence compact. Observe that every matrix $m\in S$ is of full rank. Hence the quotient space of $S$ is $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$, which is compact.

---

Finally, the dimension of $G_k(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is $k(n-k)$, because the system of equations $Mx=y$ has $k^2$ independent equations. There is a trick to observe this:

Suppose $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$ are two $k$-dimensional differentiable manifolds, $p\in \Sigma_1,q\in \Sigma_2$, the rows of $x$ is a basis of $T_p\Sigma_1$ and the rows of $y$ is a basis of $T_q\Sigma_2$. Then $v\mapsto Mv$ is a map from $T_p\Sigma_1$ to $T_q\Sigma_2$, which has $k^2$ degrees of freedom.

---

From what I have achieved so far, it seems there's no big change if we subsitute $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Where did you compute the rank ?

Comment: @Amathsfreak, the rank is assumed to be full, so that the $k$ row vectors will not degenerate, since we want it to the representative a $k$-dimensional subspace.

Comment: It is analogous to that in the homogeneous coordinate of the projective space $P^n(\mathbb{C})$, say $[x_1, \ldots, x_{n+1}]$, we require at least one $x_i$ to be non-zero. Since we have multiple rows, the requirement becomes that of full rank.

Comment: I did not understand how you computed the rank.

Comment: @Amathsfreak, the rank of a matrix is the number of elements in the maximal set of  linear independent row vectors (or column vectors, the result is the same). I'm sure you can find some useful material in any Linear Algebra textbook.